# Linear transformations proof

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a finite vector space $V$ and a linear transformation $A:V \rightarrow V$. Prove $V = KerA \oplus ImA$, if $A^2 = 3A$

Comment: I do, I'm just not sure how to use the fact that A^2 = 3A

Comment: @FedericoFallucca The transformation $A(x,y)=(y,0)$ has the non-zero vector $(1,0)$ in the kernel $A(1,0)=(0,0)$ and in the image $A(0,1)=(1,0)$. Therefore, $V$ is not a direct sum of its kernel and its image. The rank nullity theorem is a relation between dimensions only. The conclusion wanted here is an algebraic property of the spaces.

Comment: @UrošKosmač Note that for all $v\in V$ you have that $v=A(\frac{1}{3}v)+(3-A)(\frac{1}{3}v)$. Therefore $V$ is the sum of the images of $A$ and $3-A$. Now, a vector $v$ in the image of $3-A$ is of the form $(3-A)w$. But $A(3-A)w=(3A-A^2)w=0$. Therefore, the image of $3-A$ is included in the kernel of $A$. Converselly, if $Av=0$, then $v=A(\frac{1}{3}v)+(3-A)(\frac{1}{3}v)=(3-A)(\frac{1}{3}v)$ is in the image of $3-A$. Therefore, the image of $3-A$ is the kernel of $A$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy You’re right, sorry. I’m wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that

$ker(A)\cap Im(A)=\{0\}$

because if $v\in ker(A)\cap Im(A)$ then

$v=A(w)$

but

$3v=3A(w)=A^2(w)=A(v)=0$

Moreover for each $v\in V$ we observe that

$3v=(A(v)-3v)+A(v)$

with $A(v)-3v\in ker(A)$ and

$A(v)\in In(A)$

Comment: Thanks, I understand